# GeoJSON convert Polygons and MultiPolygons to LineStrings and MultiLineStrings

Tags: polygon, geojson, linestring, rasterio

Is there a gdal or python based tool for converting Polygons and MultiPolygons inside of GeoJSON to LineStrings and MultiLineStrings? I'm using rasterio / rio rasterize or gdal_rasterize to rasterize GeoTIFF w/ GeoJSON.

I need to read in GeoJSON files and be able to convert any (Multi)Polygons into LineStrings and MultiLineStrings so I can rasterize just the boundary or outline of the (Multi)Polygons onto GeoTIFFs (this includes exterior and interior polygons) and not have it fill in the entire shape.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read how linestrings and polygons are encoded in GeoJSON from https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6. It might not be too hard to change the names of the types and remove some brackets with a script from the GeoJSON text at least if your polygons do not have holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ogr2ogr you can do it with the SQLite dialect and the ExteriorRing function from SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

Test with ogrinfo and shapefile

```
ogrinfo polygons.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select exteriorring(geometry) from polygons limit
 1"
INFO: Open of `polygons.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (453.000000, 636.000000) - (598.000000, 736.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = exteriorring(geometry)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  LINESTRING (453 683,598 736,564 636,453 683)
```

This should work for you:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect SQLite -sql "select exteriorring(geometry) from my_layer" output.json my_file.json
```

Check first with `ogrinfo my_file.json` what is the layer name in your source data.

I believe that you can use the same SQL of SQlite dialect directly as an input for gdal_rasterize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html without creating an interim file.

Comment: Thanks that works for exterior, but need to somehow select all the potential interior rings as well, looks like you have to specify a particular interior ring by a known index  with InteriorRingN: InteriorRingN( polyg Polygon , n Integer ) : LineString

I need to be able to do that dynamically in the same query for all interior rings too

Comment: Please edit your question, you wrote `so I can rasterize just the "boundary" or "exterior"`.

Comment: updated, sorry for confusion.

Comment: replacing exteriorring(geometry) with boundary(geometry) worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

User 31084 is on the right track. You can do what you want to do with nothing more than Python and its json module.

The exterior ring of a GeoJSON Polygon `p` as a LineString is:

`{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': p['coordinates'][0]}`

The exterior rings of the members of a GeoJSON MultiPolygon `m` as a MultiLineString is:

`{'type': 'MultiLineString', 'coordinates': [p[0] for p in m['coordinates']]}`

Answer (score 1):

i think shapely is what you need...

for example, to open a geojson in a dictionary format just do:

```
from shapely import geometry
json = {'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[0,0],[0,10],[10,10],[10,0],[0,0]],
[[2,2],[2,4],[4,4],[4,2],[2,2]]]}
polygon = geometry.asShape(json)
```

if you want to get the exterior ring just do polygon.exterior which will give you a LineString, or polygon.exterior.xy will give you the coordinates:

```
>>>polygon.exterior.xy
(array('d', [0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0]), array('d', [0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0]))
```

like so polygon.interiors[n] will give you the interior LineStrings

```
>>>polygon.interiors[0].xy
(array('d', [2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0]), array('d', [2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0]))
```

in the case of multipolygons shapely has a MultiPolygon iterable, and also a Collection iterable (for mixed type of features).

Hope it helps